# How to overcome error while installing oculus exe in wine

Tags: ubuntu, wine, proprietary-drivers

I recently received an Oculus quest 2, and needed to install the pc app. sadly, they only have windows support. I was attempting to use wine to install it, but when I cd'd into downloads and ran "wine ./oc.exe" it came up with the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Dawn.DawnController:_window' (4) due to: Could not load file or assembly 'Daybreak, Version=1.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

I have tried:
Installing the .NET framework

Installing the latest version of wine

None of these could solve my issue, would you please help me?

*Specs: Ubuntu Mate, wine 5.0.3*

Comment: Seriously, Kali is a special-use Linux distro: it's for penetration and nothing else. **especially** not for VR headset usage... don't trust me on that, [read what Kali says about this themselves: *you should **not** be using Kali for this*](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). The problem might persist even with other Linux distros, but installing gaming hard- and software on Kali just makes everything more complicated. I don't know how you ended up with Kali - but it's really not the system you should be using; helping you on this will just be a waste of efforts.

Comment: See also: [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I now am dual booting with Ubuntu mate. What can I do now?

Comment: so, I guess you're getting the same error? Next step is to check with the winehq app database; if it's there, it might contain hints. If there's nothing there, or the hints aren't useful, you need to start debugging the .NET application (I assume it is one, because you installed the .NET framework, so you're probably much better a .NET developer than I am)

Answer (score 0):

Wine doesn't offer 100 % compatibility, some things simply don't work. It is possible this will change in a future version of Wine, but it's not guaranteed. Oculus Setup is currently rated as *Garbage* in the [Wine Application Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=39742&iTestingId=109886) with the same error so there's probably nothing you can do (if you don't want to start with debugging Wine and .NET).

Some people mention [ALVR](https://github.com/alvr-org/ALVR) as one option for working with Oculus Quest on Linux, it has [experimental Linux support](https://github.com/alvr-org/ALVR/wiki/Building-From-Source#linux) but I've no experience with VR so this might be a completely wrong advice.